# Processing large number of files c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a program where there is a folder with very large number of files(More than thousands).I want an efficient way to "open each files and process it.Processing includes calling a database stored procedures depending on the content of the file.I have written the following code to read the content of each file.Please let me know if any improvement or alternate options.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ProcessRead().Wait();
        Console.Write("Done ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task ProcessRead()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        string folder = @"Directory";

        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        int count = 0;

        foreach (string fname in fileEntries)
        {
            if (File.Exists(fname) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("file not found: " + fname);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    count++;
                    string text = await ReadTextAsync(fname);
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }

    static async Task<string> ReadTextAsync(string filePath)
    {
        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
            bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
            int numRead;
            while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
                sb.Append(text);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is working code that you want a review of, you'll have better luck over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) - However, please spend a little bit of time properly formatting your code and post before doing so.

Comment: Yes, Code Review is a better place to ask. Make sure you include the code that calls the stored procedure, otherwise they will not be able to provide an answer (and the question might get closed).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Code Review stackexchange.

Comment: files are small size or large?

Comment: @Rob: but there are many question like "what is the fastest way to read text files" in StackOverflow and people usually ask the questioners to specify what they have done and their efforts... which is what vikk did here. So we can think whats best method to read/process a large number of files, although there is many other places to ask such question

Comment: @S.Serp you are somewhat right - this is yet another "need the bestest way to read files" question... Unfortunately like most of similar posts it claims that reading files must be done as fast as possible using methods of lowest  possible level - no real measurement how fast reading actually needs to be to satisfy overall goals, no indication that reading actually performance bottleneck (like "file processing take an hour but I must improve reading speed from .1 to .04 seconds")... Overall way too broad/opinion based question in current state.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks. but i saw some refs [like as this](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/the-fastest-way-to-read-and-process-text-files) which test different methods for manipulating text files and measure the required time and compare the results.

Comment: Since you `.Wait()` the task anyway you can just do `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fname)` and skip `ReadTextAsync`.

Comment: @S.Serp existence of articles on same topic can be a reason to downvote the post, but it does not make post more concrete or practical. I.e. replacing HDD with SSD significantly speeds up file reads but is it an option or will it help OP is impossible to tell in current state of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depends on many parameters like as file size... but you can try avoid `StringBuilder` append with the following code and check if it has better performance for you:

```
byte[] data;
int n;

using (FileStream sourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    n = (int)sourceStream.Length;
    data = new byte[n];
    await sourceStream.ReadAsync(result, 0, n);
}

return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, n);
```

you can also use `FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan` when open the FileStream. the SequentialScan flag indicates that the file is to be accessed sequentially from beginning to end. The system can use this as a hint to optimize file caching.

see also [this link](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/the-fastest-way-to-read-and-process-text-files)